# Combinatorics Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to make a list of numbers. 
Rules:

1. 12 numbers in a string;
2. First number its always "1";
3. Numbers 2-3 its an items from array = [05..15];
4. 4-5 its always "78";
5. 6-7 its an items from array = [02,03,04,07,08,09,10,11,12,15..27];
6. 8-12 its all options of five-digit numbers;

I wrote this code:

```
file = File.new('./file.txt', 'w')
one = 1

(5..15).to_a.each do |two_three|
  if two_three.to_s.length == 1
    two_three = "0#{two_three}"
  end

  four_five = 78

  arr1 = (2..27).to_a
  arr2 = [0,1,5,6,13,14]
  arr3 = arr1-arr2
  arr3.each do |six_seven|
    if six_seven.to_s.length == 1
      six_seven = "0#{six_seven}"
    else 
      six_seven = "#{six_seven}"
    end

    Array.new(100000) do |index|
      index = index + 1

      if index.to_s.length == 1
        eight_twelve = "0000#{index}"
      elsif index.to_s.length == 2
        eight_twelve = "000#{index}"
      elsif index.to_s.length == 3
        eight_twelve = "00#{index}"
      elsif index.to_s.length == 4
        eight_twelve = "0#{index}"
      end

      file.puts "#{one}#{two_three}#{four_five}#{six_seven}#{eight_twelve}"
    end
  end
end
```

Its working, but incorrectly. 
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mpZL.png)
And continues to jump throughout all results (return thirteen-digit only on at string number 200000).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Weird requirements. Why do you need to create such an array? Perhaps a proper class might be more better?

Comment: @spickermann, year, i know. This is like an registration datas. About classes, i dont know. Im not an pro developer. Its just an amateur project. Could you help me?

Comment: Seems like you have some typos or incorrect code near `Array.new(100000) do |index| index + 1`. If your index is nil `eight_twelve` would be nil as well, because you are not checking for string of length 0. Moreover you can reduce many if/else conditionals in your code and improve readability by using `format` function `format("%01d%02d%02d%02d%05d", one, two_three, four_five, six_seven, eight_twelve)`

Answer (score 1):

[Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-product) is the method of choice here.

First construct the following array.

```
arr = [['1'], [*'05'..'15'], ['78'], [*'02'..'04', *'07'..'12', *'15'..'27'],
       [*'00000'..'99999']]
  #=> [["1"], ["05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"],
  #    ["78"], ["02", "03", "04", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "15",
  #     "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27"],
  #     "00000", "00001",..., "99999"]
```

The sizes of each element (array) of `arr` is as follows.

```
arr.map(&:size)
  #=> [1, 11, 1, 22, 100000]
```

To generate all combinations of arrays obtained by selecting one element from each element (array) of `arr` and then converting the resultant array to a string we write the following (which takes awhile to execute):

```
combos = arr.first.product(*arr.drop(1)).map(&:join)
n = combos.size
  #=> 24200000

combos.first(2)
  #=> ["105780200000", "105780200001"]
combos.last(2)
  #=> ["115782799998", "115782799999"]
5.times do
  i = rand(n)
  puts "%5d -> %s" % [i, combos[i]]
end
 9379583 -> 109780979583
12310295 -> 110781910295
11619403 -> 110781019403
 3571703 -> 106781971703
18237011 -> 113781037011
```

Note:

```
size.reduce(:*)
  #=> 24200000
```

Comment: "takes awhile to execute" – And that is why "combinatorial explosion" is called combinatorial **explosion**.